# How to deserialize a Map with integer key in java

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, flexjson

I have been using flexjson api to serialize and deserialize a map with integer keys.
Now while deserializing the map keys gets converted to string. Is there some way in which the keys can be retained as integer.

Here is a sample code block

```
Map<Integer,Object> map = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
map.put(1, "a");
map.put(2,"b");
flexjson.JSONSerializer serializer = new flexjson.JSONSerializer();
String serializedMapString = serializer.serialize(map);

flexjson.JSONDeserializer<Map<Integer,Object>> deserializer = new flexjson.JSONDeserializer<Map<Integer,Object>>();
Map<Integer,Object> deserializedMap = deserializer.deserialize(serializedMapString);

for(Integer key: deserializedMap.keySet()){
System.out.println(key+"-"+deserializedMap.get(key));
}
```

The deserialization doesn't give any errors, but the keys get converted to String.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with [Genson](http://owlike.github.io/genson/) like that:

```
Genson genson = new Genson();
Map<Integer, Object> result = genson.deserialize(json, new GenericType<Map<Integer, Object>>() {});
```